# iOS - iAds not loading

Tags: ios, iad

We have recently made an app and weve added iAds.

After being released to the appstore, we tested the game. Everything worked fine with the iAds loading each time the app was started.

After opening and closing the app about 10 times, the iAds have stopped showing up.

Even after deleting the app and reinstalling it, the ads do not load.

Does anyone know why this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apple only has so many ads to give out. When the iAd Banner View is on screen it requests an ad but one is not always available to fill it. That is why you need to implement the ADBannerViewDelegate methods for when the banner fails to receive an ad to remove it from the screen. Something like this:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [banner removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Then when you get the delegate call for a successful load you can put it back.

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    [self.view addSubview:banner];
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

You'll notice in iTunes Connect if you look at your iAd Network data you will get an average fill rate along with other info.